# Where can I get a new shield?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

My shield broke and I'm not sure where I can buy a new shield. So, where can I buy a new shield?

Comment: @JeffMercado I'm voting to leave this open as the suspected duplicate asks what happens when the shield breaks, while this one asks where he can buy one. While related, they're not sharing the same answers

Comment: @Oak it's all the same. His shield broke, he has options. He chose for a specific option, the duplicated question asks for them all (if not worded specifically that way).

Comment: @JeffMercado Yes, but the **Where** part (imo) is what makes it different. Then again it's just my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the [Gear Shop in the Bazaar](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Gear_Shop) sells [wooden](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Wooden_Shield#The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Skyward_Sword), [iron](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Iron_Shield#The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Skyward_Sword), and [sacred shields](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Sacred_Shield).

The wooden shield also appears to be repairable at the [Scrap Shop](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Scrap_Shop).  Note that the iron and sacred shields become available for purchase after doing certain quests.